# caddy laravel docker compose file not found

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, caddy

I am trying to setup laravel and caddy in a docker environment.

This is my Caddyfile

```
:80 {
    root * /app/public
    encode gzip
    php_fastcgi php:9000
    file_server
}
```

This is my Dockerfile for php/laravel:

```
# Use the official PHP image as the base
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy composer.json and composer.lock to the container
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .


# Set permissions for Laravel storage and bootstrap cache folders
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
    storage \
    bootstrap/cache


# Expose port 9000
EXPOSE 9000

# Start the PHP-FPM server
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  caddy:
      image: caddy
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
        - caddy_data:/data
        - caddy_config:/config
        - caddy_certs:/root/.caddy
        - ./Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
        - ../app:/app
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 443:443

  php:
    build:
      context: ../app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ../app:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 9000:9000

volumes:
  caddy_data:
  caddy_config:
  caddy_certs:
```

When I send a request I get file not found, but checking php container logs i get "GET /index.php" 404.

Anybody have an idea what is wrong with my configuration. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like it could be something about the different directories you are using for the web hosting root. Can just use `/app` as the WORKDIR/working_dir and not bother with volume mapping of `/var/www/html`? The web server is definitely responding, it just isn't serving from a directory that has an index.php file.

Comment: @EricWoods I'm sorry, can you explain a bit more what you want me to try? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, basically anywhere in your Dockerfile and your docker-compose.yml that has `/var/www/html` try replacing those with `/app`. I haven't specifically used Caddy, but I've done lots with Docker and Laravel, so this is mostly an educated guess.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, your intuition was correct. Setting up with the same folder worked. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it running.